# Error while building the workspace from command line using eclipsec

Tags: java, eclipse

I use an eclipse plugin. When I clean and rebuild all projects in my workspace from Eclipse using Project->Clean option, it is successfully.

However , when i use eclipse utility like this:
`C:\Program Files\Eclipse\eclipsec.exe -noSplash -data "C:\MAK\Workspace\TST\aba" -application org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.aptBuild"`

It doesn't generate the class files. The logs show errors and exceptions like:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator  for bundle is invalid
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workbench has not been created yet.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.lawson.mak.ui (9).
```

Answer (score 0):

It look like the plugin you use (com.lawson.mak.ui) has a dependency to Eclipse's `Workbench`.

But by not running GUI you don't start ui plugins (in which Workbench exists).

Comment: Hey Michal, I need to use eclipsec utility as I need to generate class files without opening eclipse and manually running the Project->Clean option. Also I am new to plugin development. The plugin has been developed by someone else. Can you help me know what standard files(if there are any in this case) should i make the changes in so that this exception can be removed .